# Using PNGs in Turtle Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm searching for a way to use PNGs as a Turtle Shape or a Background Picture in a Turtle window.

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from turtle import *

t = Turtle()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Turtle.png"))
register_shape("Pic", Shape("image", img))
t.shape(img)
```

When I start this Code, I'm always getting this error Code:

```
raise TurtleGraphicsError("There is no shape named %s" % name)
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: There is no shape named pyimage2
```

I heard that you are able to use PNGs in a python Code with PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open())
Some idea how to get this code working?
*Using Python 3.6.4*

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the name under which you registered your image. Try this:

```
t.shape("Pic")
```

Reference:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.shape
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.register_shape

Comment: This doesn't work with png though, only gif, if I'm not mistaken.